# Flutter Project properties?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I have been using Android Studio, after a while Emulators stopped working, next - USB plugged smartphone stopped working, basically Android Studio keeps falling apart day by day for no reason, so I decided to reinstall all that mess.

Now I have some projects in "Android Studio Projects", but when I try to run them, I get all kinds of errors, because previously the dart, flutter, android studio etc folders were saved in different locations. These are not global settings, but project settings. Where can I fix those?

Comment: Now you want to run your project or something else?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to run my old projects that refer to old foldersturcture

Comment: Run "flutter doctor" on cmd

Comment: And post the result in here, please.

Comment: [!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.

And just to be sure I have literally reinstalled both packages right before